# Application validation with whatsapp

Tags: authentication, token, one-time-password

Friends,
Currently we have a lot of apps (including WhatsApp, Facebook, and so on) that make the OTP via SMS. I was thinking if there is a way to send an 'Authentication code', but in this case via WhatsApp instead of SMS, or another instant messenger, and a way to make the same automatic recognition, avoiding the need of manual insertion by the user.
Is there any service or API that make it possible?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's already implemented, here you can find ore information:
https://www.protectimus.com/protectimus-bot